# SharePoint 2013 oAuth URL to get token

Tags: development, security-token-service

here  is  the   idea:  i  want  to  make  php  web  site   which  will  be  hosted  on  my  server  and  it   will  work  with  my  sharepoint 2013 site   hosted  on  office365.

my sharepoint 2013 site   is   smeasy.sharepoint.com 
I   have  read   msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj687469.aspx  and  registered  App  with  smeasy.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx ,  after  this   I   have  assigned  rights   with   smeasy.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx

also i  have  created  oAuth   url

https://smeasy-my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/OAuthAuthorize.aspx?client_id=71b572ee-cfc9-49b0-a324-a8cc8ff77f5f&scope=Site.Manage&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdev-v.smestorage.com%2F%3Fp%3Doauthlogin%26action%3Dcomplete%26pr_id%3D50%26type%3Dempty2%26spoint2013%3Dy

and   got   **code**   in  response.

The question is: how  to  get   token  by  code  in  php (what  url  to  pass  this   code   and   how),  i  just  can not   find   the   way  how  to  do  this   maybe   you   may help  me  and point   to  article?  or   at  least   let  me  know   if   this   possible   because  right  now   i  am  not   sure  that  this   is   possible  on  remote  server  (not   azure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is you can't (Or it isn't designed so you can) get the token from your php you need to generate it from the app.

Take a look at the tips and tricks page for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179932%28v=office.15%29#Tokens

and also high trust

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179932%28v=office.15%29#S2S

Answer (score 4):

you can get the access token by making a POST request to

```
https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/<site_realm>/tokens/OAuth/2
```

with required post parameters in the body.
this will return the access token and refresh token which you can use to make REST calls to sharepoint online site and to regenerate the access token once it expires.

refer this post for the complete flow:

[SharePoint Online (O365) OAuth Authentication](http://spshell.blogspot.in/2015/03/sharepoint-online-o365-oauth.html)