# Is it possible to POST to a list that requires OAuth, through just js?

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest

I'm (very) new to SharePoint, and have been tasked with creating what was described as a "lightweight Angular form" to submit items to a list. The form is supposed to be embedded into a page, so it's nothing too grand.

However, the project has been giving me no end of authentication problems.

---

I've found a few resources that seem to pertain almost directly to my situation.

- [Your entire approach is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804624/how-can-i-get-an-oauth-access-token-in-sharepoint-2013)
- [You'll need an app](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69617/sharepoint-2013-oauth-url-to-get-token)

---

Am I correct in my assumption that the approach I've been taking will not work?
Is there an obvious solution that I'm missing?

Comment: Is this form a SharePoint page? If so, you need to use the request digest that should be on the page in order to do any POST requests.  If this is an app, then you have to do the oauth dance, which isn't difficult with the classes that Microsoft bundles in apps.  I can't say for certain without seeing what you're trying, but it should be doable regardless.

Comment: @wjervis actually you need request digest for every POST, no matter are you in SharePoint or not...

Comment: @Kai, not if you have a bearer token

Comment: @wjervis yes, this is the only exception. But I can call SharePoint from outside without bearer token.

Comment: @Kai, Really? Didn't know that.  Thought the bearer token was required.  Though, I suppose if you can authenticate with your credentials, then you wouldn't need oauth, and then the digest would be needed again.

Comment: @wjervis yep, you can authenticate with cookie, NTLM header. Bearer (oauth) is only one of the options.

Comment: This will eventually be injected into a sharepoint app, so I should be able to take advantage of the digest token there. I'm a little out of luck insofar as local testing, though, as I'm not sure if there's a sandbox environment set up.